# How can I give all tabs in page height based on the biggest rise for the biggest tab among them

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How can I give all tabs in page height based on the biggest rise for the biggest tab among them

> example

```
<div id="" class="tab-pane fade  in active">
    <ul class="autoValidate nav nav-tabs nav-justified nav-thirdlevel hidden-xs">
        <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab1">tab1</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab2">tab2</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab3">tab3</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="panel-group visible-xs" id="undefined-accordion"></div>
    <div class="tab-content tab-contentlevel hidden-xs stander-Page-Height">
        <div id="tab1" class="tab-pane fade active in"> // for example this tab height is 400px
            // something....
        </div>
        <div id="tab2" class="tab-pane fade"> // for example this tab height is 600px
            // something....
        </div>
        <div id="tab3" class="tab-pane fade"> // for example this tab height is 500px
            // something....
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**How i can take every tabs in the page the height 600px for example using (css || js || jquery)**

Thanks you so much UW

Answer (score 0):

```
.tab-content { 
    display:flex; 
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: strech
    // other css rules
}
```

With align-items set to `strech` all child will  be force to fill the height of their parent.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following CSS and all tab will take the height of 600px.

```
.tab-content {
  display: flex;
  height: 600px;
  align-items: stretch;
}
.tab-pane {
  display: block;
  margin: 10px;
  background: red;
}
```

EDIT: Added code snippet.

```css
.tab-content {
  display: flex;
  height: 600px;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.tab-pane {
  display: block;
  margin: 10px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
  <ul class="autoValidate nav nav-tabs nav-justified nav-thirdlevel hidden-xs">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab1">tab1</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab2">tab2</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab3">tab3</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="panel-group visible-xs" id="undefined-accordion"></div>
  <div class="tab-content tab-contentlevel hidden-xs stander-Page-Height">
    <div id="tab1" class="tab-pane fade active in"> // for example this tab height is 400px // something....
    </div>
    <div id="tab2" class="tab-pane fade"> // for example this tab height is 600px // something....
    </div>
    <div id="tab3" class="tab-pane fade"> // for example this tab height is 500px // something....
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: I tried it and it was adding the height of 600 px to tab content. Can you please elaborate what you think is not working ?

Comment: @DinaDiagovic add code snippet let me know what is it that is incorrect?